# How do I build ROS VLP16 Velodyne driver for Indigo using Catkin

Tags: velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am a noob to both linux and ROS. I installed ROS indigo and the velodyne stack. Later, I found that the apt-get version does not contain the vlp16_points.launch. I have read other posts in this ROS answers forum discussing about building the velodyne package from source using catkin. There aren't any instructions in the velodyne github page either explaining this procedure. Can someone tell me how to build this package (https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne) using catkin_make in Ubuntu? Should I just clone it to a folder and invoke catkin_make from that folder? I really need help regarding this build procedure as I need to get this up running ASAP.  Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226594/how-do-i-build-ros-vlp16-velodyne-driver-for-indigo-using-catkin/) by [krishnaece1505](https://answers.ros.org/users/25947/krishnaece1505/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2016-02-14

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

First, build a catkin workspace:

```
$ source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash
$ mkdir -p ~/catkin_ws/src
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/src
$ git clone https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne.git
```

Install all the dependencies:

```
$ cd ..
$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro indigo -y
```

Then, build everything:

```
$ catkin_make
$ source devel/setup.bash
```

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2016-02-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [krishnaece1505](https://answers.ros.org/users/25947/krishnaece1505/) on 2016-02-15**:
Thank you:) I successfully got the drivers into my Ubuntu machine! But, now I have a problem receiving the UDP packets in the Ubuntu Virtual machine. I will probably post a separate question for that!

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2016-02-15**:
Yes, please make that a separate question. Your virtual machine may not be configured correctly. You can use `wireshark` to see if any packets are being received.

**Comment by [ixorim](https://answers.ros.org/users/33058/ixorim/) on 2017-12-29**:
http://velodynelidar.com/docs/manuals/63-9266%20REV%20A%20WEBSERVER%20USER%20GUIDE,HDL-32E%20&%20VLP-16.pdf